# Remove restore button from maximized tabs in .NEt

Tags: c#

i am developing an application in C#.Net in which i have implemented mdi.all mdi childs are opened in maximized state in tabs. i want tabs to have only the "close" button. but whenever a child is opened minimize ad restore buttons appear with it.. i CAN disable the minimize button but what to do with RESTORE button. i haven't found any way to tackle this problem. Can anyony please help me

Comment: Could you provide some details on how you are doing that? Are you using some existing framework for this? How do you render tabs?

Comment: im doing this in c# using visual studio.net. 1st i made my application mdi. then using the tab control of visual studio i made all the childs open in tabs.

Comment: well i cant get what do you mean by "render tabs"

Comment: this.ActiveMdiChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; TabPage tpage = new TabPage(this.ActiveMdiChild.Text); tpage.Tag = this.ActiveMdiChild; tpage.Parent =tabForms; /*tabForms is the tabControl of the form*/ tabForms.SelectedTab = tpage;

Comment: @Groo i hope the above code lines will help you understand what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Set the [ControlBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox.aspx)  property  MaximizeBox and MinimizedBox  to false.

Comment: This doesn't work. The "Restore" button still shows (per OP), but then you just aren't able to minimize or maximize it after it has been restored

Answer (score -1):

Change the `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedDialog`

Comment: @jia can you provide some screenshot?